# Gradle build - aapt doesn't exist

Tags: android, build, gradle, aapt

I have problem when building with gradle. It says that aapt doesn't exist, but aapt exists and have chmod 0777.
Code is ok, building with Ant works.

I give output:
    :mergeDebugResources FAILED

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.
> /home/nikodem/Workshop/PlanLekcji/res/drawable-mdpi/pt.png: Error: Cannot run program "/home/nikodem/Programy/AndroidSDK/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory
```

/home/nikodem/Workshop/PlanLekcji/res/drawable-mdpi/pt.png is valid path to picture.
/home/nikodem/Programy/AndroidSDK/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt is valid path to aapt.

Answer (score 6):

Just install these two packages for aapt and it'll be alright ;)

(Write these commands in your terminal window)

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it with

```
chmod +x /Android/Sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt
```

After this my project built without errors.

Answer (score 0):

I met this issue, so google for two hours, tried "install lib32stdc++6", but still not work, finnally, I just go to /AndroidSDK/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt, in the terminal, I use ./aapt , it popped errors like "./aapt: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory", I google and install this package and continue use  ./aapt, it popped  missing other packages, after install several, it finnally worked ,I think it is the final way to solve it. hope it helped